# Display contents of a text file in Django template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I am attempting to create a file in simple website and then read the contents of the same in a variable inside a Django view function and parse the variable to the template to be displayed on web page.
However, when I print the variable, it appears the same on cmd as is in the original text file, but the output on the web page has no formattings but appears like a single string.

I've been stuck on it for two days.

**Also I'm relatively new to django and self learning it**

```
file1 = open(r'status.txt','w',encoding='UTF-8')
file1.seek(0)
for i in range(0,len(data.split())):

        file1.write(data.split()[i] + "          ")
        if i%5==0 and i!=0 and i!=5:
        file1.write("\n")
        file1.close()

file1 = open(r'status.txt',"r+",encoding='UTF-8')
d = file1.read()
print(d) #prints on cmd in the same formatting as in text file
return render(request,'status.html',{'dat':d}) **#the html displays it only as a single text 
string**
```

```
<body>

{% block content %}

        {{dat}}

{% endblock %}

</body>
```

[image: Link to image with html page display]

Answer (score 1):

Use the [linebreaks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) filter in your template. It will render `\n` as `<br/>`.

use it like -:
`{{ dat | linebreaks }}`

from the docs:

> Replaces line breaks in plain text with appropriate HTML; a single
>   newline becomes an HTML line break (`<br>`) and a new line followed by a
>   blank line becomes a paragraph break (`</p>`).

You can use [linebreaksbr](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr) if you don't want `<p>` tag.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But as you can see in my code the extra white spaces i give in between to make it look sorted are removed while diplaying on webpage. I tried searching for filters but they work for removing white spaces and not keeping them

Answer (score 0):

It's because in HTML newline is `</br>` in Python it is `\n`. You should convert it, before rendering

```
mytext = "<br />".join(mytext.split("\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending of your needs and the file format you want to print, you may also want to check the [<pre> HTML tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre).